# Trying to get rid of C:\inetpub ... in use?

Tags: windows-10, services

I have finally upgraded to Windows 10, and noticed in my root C, that there is a directory named `inetpub`. In it is `temp\appPools`. Trying to delete it (because I don't have nor want IIS on), results in an error that it is in use.

Upon digging, I cannot find any clear answers as how to turn off (or what is safe to turn off), to get rid of this directory. I have "Internet Information Services" disabled, and also the ".NET 3.5 Windows Communication Foundations" off. From what I've read, turning those off, I should be able to delete the directory without issue.

Somehow I think it is tied up in "Windows Process Activation Services" ... but have no idea if it is safe to turn that off.

This is my current Windows Features:

[image]

Suggestions?

Comment: You might want to have a look at this page, part of the Stack Exchange sites, if you are hosting.... https://serverfault.com/questions/591190/deleted-deleted-temp-apppools-folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe to turn off "Windows Process Activation Service" and yes, this is probably the culprit.

> If you don’t have any plans to run a home-based server, then you 
>   should **turn off**
> *Windows Process Activation Service*.
>   
> It’s also known as **Internet Information Services (IIS)**, 
>   which helped developers to write apps and building their projects. 
>   If you are a regular Windows user, just turn it off.
>   [11 Unnecessary Features You Can Disable In Windows 10](https://whatsabyte.com/windows/disable-unnecessary-windows10-features/)

Comment: Ok, but is a "Home-based server" also something when considering "hosting a game", or "allowing smb file access" ? Which is what had me pause when thinking if WPAS could be disabled.